# Sort string with lowercase first in case of same alphabet type

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, char, locale

How to sort a `std::string` with lowercase first in case of same alphabet type?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    
    int main() {
        std::string str = "aAbBcCdDeE";
        std::sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str));
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
```

Current Output:

```
    ABCDEabcde
```

Expected Output:

```
    aAbBcCdDeE
```

Comment: Add your own compare function to the call of std::sort

Comment: Might be a better test case if it weren't already properly sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You can using a custom compare operator like this (demo : https://onlinegdb.com/Z95sro0L4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// an example function may not be correct for all alphabets
bool compare_lower_case_first(const char lhs, const char rhs)
{
    return (std::islower(lhs) && (std::toupper(lhs) == rhs)) || (std::tolower(lhs) < std::tolower(rhs));
}

int main() 
{
    std::string str{"ABCDEFabcdef"};
    std::sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str), compare_lower_case_first);
    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "aAbBcCdDeE";

    auto cmp = []( char c1, char c2 )
    {
        char left = std::tolower( ( unsigned char )c1 );
        char right = std::tolower( ( unsigned char )c2 );

        return ( left < right ) or ( not( right < left ) and std::isupper( ( unsigned char )c2 ) );
    };

    std::sort( std::begin( str ), std::end( str ), cmp );

    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
aAbBcCdDeE
```

Comment: The `or`, `and`, and `not` look like some Python snuck into your subconscious while you were entering the answer. Might want to get an exterminator to look at that.

Comment: @Chris `or`, `and`, and `not` are perfectly valid synonyms for `||`, `&&`, and `!`, respectively.